# configure an interface, which i want to survive reboot

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking

I want to configure an interface for the virtual box, which is installed within my ubuntu machine. When i create it manually it works:

```
vboxmanage hostonlyif create
vboxmanage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.56.1
```

by checking ifconfig, It is there :

[image]

I want to make these changes survive a reboot and set automatically during system startup.For that what i did is:

`sudo mkdir /opt/systemd/` then
`sudo mkdir /opt/systemd/` then
`sudo nano /opt/systemd/vboxhostonly` and copy the following code into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
vboxmanage hostonlyif create
vboxmanage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.56.1
```

then Ctrl + X to exit , Y to save and enter to write file.

Then I make the file executable

```
cd /opt/systemd/ then sudo chmod a+x vboxhostonly
```

the I create a service so

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/vboxhostonlynic.service
```

Then I Edit the file by typing `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/vboxhostonlynic.service` and then typing in:

```
Description=Setup VirtualBox Hostonly Adapter
After=vboxdrv.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/systemd/vboxhostonly
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then Ctrl + X to exit , Y to save and enter to write file.

Now to install the service and ensure it loads at boot time I type:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable vboxhostonlynic.service
```

But when i reboot the machine the interface is not there, any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `bash` script can't find `vboxmanage`, because `vboxmanage` isn't in any directory in the script's `$PATH`. Try using the full path to `vboxmanage` (`type -p vboxmanage`), but you might have to move more of your environment to the script.

Jobs run through `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `systemd` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`). Other needed environment variables may need help, too.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.